# Why are multiple mutable borrows possible in the same scope?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I wrote this code that borrows a mutable variable more than once and compiles without any error, but according to [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references) this should not compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    println!("{}", s);
    test_three(&mut s);
    println!("{}", s);
    test_three(&mut s);
    println!("{}", s);
}

fn test_three(st: &mut String) {
    st.push('f');
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2817e3a0ebf5b39a3f41fad3c68edda7&version=undefined))

Is this a bug or there is new feature in Rust?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing weird happens here; the mutable borrow becomes void every time the `test_three` function concludes its work (which is right after it's called):

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    println!("{}", s); // immutably borrow s and release it
    test_three(&mut s); // mutably borrow s and release it
    println!("{}", s); // immutably borrow s and release it
    test_three(&mut s); // mutably borrow s and release it
    println!("{}", s); // immutably borrow s and release it
}
```

The function doesn't hold its argument - it only mutates the `String` it points to and releases the borrow right afterwards, because it is not needed anymore:

```
fn test_three(st: &mut String) { // st is a mutably borrowed String
    st.push('f'); // the String is mutated
} // the borrow claimed by st is released
```

Comment: I wrote similar code few month ago with older rust compiler and I got compile error, something like this "can not borrow mutable more than once".
but now it's working with version 1.20.

Comment: @mojtab23 actually this is nothing new and should work fine since Rust 1.0; it compiles without issues with [godbolt's rustc 1.0](https://rust.godbolt.org). The code you are referring to probably had some significant (even if subtle at first glance) difference.